# how to concatenate all rows of a column of a data frame in pandas without group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a dataframe like this

Have been on it 12 days  along with 60 mg prozac 4+ years on that.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  index  sentences

```
  1   I feel the best I have felt in years.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  2   "I have taken for over 7 years.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  3   I slept 2 hours".                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  4   IT SAVED MY LIFE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  5   IT SAVED MY LIFE"
```

then I want to concatenate them in one array. the problem is that there maybe some sentences reptitive but still I want to keep all of them so the result will be:

```
["I feel the best I have felt in years", "I have taken for over 7 years." , "I slept 2 hours." , "IT SAVED MY LIFE" , "IT SAVED MY LIFE"]
```

I have tries this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944078/concatenate-rows-of-a-data-frame)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250019/how-to-concatenate-the-row-names-of-a-data-frame-with-a-special-character) which both are in r.

I have also tried this approach:

```
dfsent.groupby(['sentences']).apply(','.join)
```

but as some of the rows in my data frame are repetitive it give me only one of them. in case of my example return me this:

```
["I feel the best I have felt in years", "I have taken for over 7 years." , "I slept 2 hours." , "IT SAVED MY LIFE" ]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't you just want `df.sentences.tolist()`? You can then join that if you want.

Comment: you are right , It just gave me the correct answer. thank you so much. do you want add your answer?

Comment: No thanks, I think this might be a duplicate question, just happy to help :)

Comment: well its not duplicate at all, as in the question it want to convert to a list but my purpose was to concatenate them. so I did not know I can find this question with putting my word in another way, thanks by the way :)

Comment: Do you want a single string as the result? If so use `df.sentences.str.cat(sep=',')`  I think that might be what you really want, if that's the case I'll reopen the question as not a dupe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all you want is to produce a list of all the values (unique or not) in a column in your Pandas dataframe, the easier method would be to use the `.tolist()` method.

So, `dfsent['sentences'].tolist()` would produce the desired output.